# How to detect when an AWS instance is fully functional

Tags: amazon-web-services, bamboo

We are using Bamboo to spin up (through Powershell on the buildserver) an AWS Windows 2008 R2 instance as a target for a web deployment.

What is the best method for determining that the target instance is ready for a deployment (all services up and running, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real easy way to do this with Windows instances. Your best bet is to write a infrastructure test that looks to see if a service is running on the target environment and to keep retrying until it either verifies that the service is available or a timeout has occurred. At that point you could start your deployment.

I generally do this with a cucumber script that will check a service's status continually until it gets an answer

You could also set a timeout for an appropriate amount of time, although this option wouldn't be my recommendation